# Difference between the classes CL_GUI_DOCKING_CONTAINER and CL_GUI_SPLITTER_CONTAINER

Tags: abap, dynpro

In ABAP, what is the difference between the classes CL_GUI_DOCKING_CONTAINER and CL_GUI_SPLITTER_CONTAINER? I need to divide the screen into 3 sections, a header above and an ALV below. I'm not sure which class to use:

```
* Create main screen
  CREATE OBJECT gr_cnt_main_screen
    EXPORTING
      repid                       = g_repid
      dynnr                       = g_dynnr
      side                        = cl_gui_docking_container=>dock_at_top
      ratio                       = co_ratio_095
    EXCEPTIONS
      cntl_error                  = 1
      cntl_system_error           = 2
      create_error                = 3
      lifetime_error              = 4
      lifetime_dynpro_dynpro_link = 5
      OTHERS                      = 6.

  IF  sy-subrc NE 0.
    RETURN.
  ENDIF.
```

or use:

```
* Split main in Header & list
  CREATE OBJECT gr_cnt_splitter_main
    EXPORTING
      parent            = gr_cnt_main_screen
      rows              = 2
      columns           = 1
    EXCEPTIONS
      cntl_error        = 1
      cntl_system_error = 2
      OTHERS            = 3.

  IF  sy-subrc NE 0.
    RETURN.
  ENDIF.
```

Thanks!

Comment: It depends what you want to do and what UI technology you want at the top... It may end in mixing both container controls. It depends. The "docking" adds a container at a side of the main screen (non-control-based UI technology = classic Dynpro). The "splitter" splits a container into several ones. A container may be created in three ways: custom control area in a Dynpro screen + CL_GUI_CUSTOM_CONTAINER, CL_GUI_DIALOGBOX_CONTAINER (amodal popup) or CL_GUI_DOCKING_CONTAINER.

Comment: I'm using classic dynpro, since I have to make 3 containers that I have to use Splitter class. Thanks!

Comment: What I mean by "classic Dynpro" here is the use of field-like UI elements of the classic Dynpro which cannot be used inside containers, in that case you *must* use a docking container and the "top container" wouldn't be a container but the Dynpro screen with classic UI elements. If you use a Control (CL_GUI*) in the top part, then a container is fine. The answer to your question is that it depends based on your exact need so you should clarify what you want to do exactly.